# How to create a mutable dataframe and keep streaming rows appending to it in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark streaming source to read data from. I want to read data from this source and keep appending to a mutable DataFrame so that at the end of the stream (when I stop the streaming), I will have a DataFrame in Spark memory for further operation.

> How to achieve it?

**Note:** I am aware that everything in Spark is Lazy load and would not be possible for any operation outside of the Spark streaming. However, what I am targeting is to "cache" the data in Spark memory while streaming and then I want to use this cached dataframe after streaming.

Comment: Seach for stateful streaming processing - mapStateWithKey will be your teammate! :)

Comment: Sounds like Structured Streaming could be a goer.

Comment: Is there a basic example to look at for such scenario?